# Why does this result in bold letters?

Tags: html, css

First of all I want to achieve a black background:
Instead of a black background I get bold letters.

HTML CODE

```
<span id="border"><h3>Title</h3>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
</span>
```

CSS CODE

```
#border {
    background-color: #000000;
}
```

Jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/tYaCK/

Comment: That’s invalid HTML btw. – span is not allowed to contain headline or paragraph elements.

Comment: Try using a [css reset](https://www.google.com/search?q=css+reset).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This bold is actually coming from your `h3` tag as a default style rather than your border css.

As for why your border isn't appearing... well that is because the span is an inline element and will not expand to contain the block level `h3` tag.

You can see this working by adding `display: inline-block;` as a style to the `h3` tag.

FYI You should not have a h3 within a span as that is not valid html. I would recommend a `div` tag as an alternative to the `span`.

Comment: +1, an answer within 20 seconds of the question? wow, that is super fast :)

Comment: I don't get how text in <p></p> gets bolded.

Comment: @ErgoProxy: The text within `<p>` doesn't get bold. It looks normal.

Comment: @ErgoProxy - uh, it doesn't? the `h3` is bold, but the `p` isn't.

Comment: Oh I had forgotten to close an <h2> tag earlier in my code that caused my <p> text to get bolded.

Answer (score 2):

Two issues:

1. The bold is the default styling of the `<h3>` tag.
2. Your black background isn't showing up because it's on a `<span>` element.

   The span defaults to `display:inline`, which means it us not valid for it to contain block elements. The `h3` is a block element.

   To fix this, either use a `div` instead of a `span`, or set the span to `display:block`.

Answer (score 1):

You could have seen the background color if the situation had been slightly different.

Consider the following HTML:

```
<span id="border">
    Some opening text...
    <h3>Title</h3>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    and some closing text.
</span>
```

I just added some text to the `span` element.

And for the CSS, just add a color so you can see the text:

```
#border {
    color: green;
    background-color: #000000;
}
```

Demo at:   http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/M8Exf/

What is happening here is that the CSS engine opens an inline block (`span`) and applies the format from `#border`.

However, upon finding the block level `h3`, the CSS engine closes off the `span` element (internally) and begins a new block level box, and similarly for the `p` element.

Upon finding the remaining text from the `span`, the CSS engine starts a new anonymous inline box and applies the same styling from `#border`.

This procedure is part of the CSS box and visual formatting model.